# how to save python session input and output

Tags: python, session, vim

All of the ways which discussed this question save the history of your commands in a file or you have to use an IDE ,I am using vim with python-mode (no mouse using) what I would like to do is to save my session as code I wrote and the python output ,So I dont have to use paper and pen to write my input and python output all what I have to do is to print out my session , I tried the code (.pystartup)
and it only save my input and I tried to redirect the output to a file and it only save the python output , is there a way to have both in one file ready to be printed out .

Comment: Very low quality question, -1

Answer (score 0):

I really cherish vim, it'S a fantastic piece of work. Nevertheless, your requirements are easier with other tools.

Probably the best choice, in my oppinion, would be to use the [ipython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html). It offers really rich features, including graphics with mpl and much more, and for me is the perfect tool for "reproducible experiments". The full state of a notebook can be saved to disk, reloaded, exported, printed etc.

You should really give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

The old "I use `$EDITOR` instead of `$IDE` because I don't want to use the mouse" bullshit… IDEs have shortcuts for everything and they all allow you to customize them to your liking. Learn them all and forget about your mouse.

Anyway, what you want is neither an editor nor an IDE; you want a REPL like [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) or [ipython](http://ipython.org/) (possibly with its notebook feature mentioned above). Both tools allow you to save and restore your sessions and are far better at "getting" your python code than Vim.

Comment: ""I use $EDITOR instead of $IDE because I don't want to use the mouse" bullshit""  , If your server crashed and you are in run level 2 or run level 3 and no mouse to use ...what would you do ?? can you use mouse ????  ....

Comment: No idea what "run level 2 and 3" have to do with using a text editor versus using an IDE nor if you actually read beyond that point and understood the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: if you are in run level 1 or 2 and you know there is a bug in a code file (for EX: oracle.conf) in line 1200 you can easily fix it by using vim ...right??